# How to decode JSON Array root with outer square brackets (and no curly brackets) using JSONDecoder unkeyedContainer

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, jsondecoder

Given following data structure:

["mJv8P81",["0","4B43AC",4,1675445326,2,3,1,47.40967,8.9179,46,956,0,267,0,0,0,7,3,0,"HB-ZQI"],["0","DE007A",9,1675445313,2,5,1,50.42467,9.19857,0,518,0,180,0,0,0,5,3,0,"TEST"],["0","DD0B25",9,1675445322,2,3,1,51.9966,8.55458,39,454,-2,293,0,0,0,7,3,0,"D-HVBI"],["0","D005CE",9,1675445326,2,3,1,52.40545,9.77742,40,304,0,324,0,0,0,7,3,0,"D-HDSX"],["0","3B7B9E",4,1675445308,2,3,1,43.89118,4.92555,47,454,-2,330,0,0,0,7,3,0,"F-ZBPM"]]

how to decode this data using JSON decoder (possibly via unkeyerContainer) using standard means i.e. foundation methods?

The decodable struct is:

```
struct udpSafeSkyPost: Decodable {

    struct adslAircraft: Decodable {
        let version: String             
        let address: String             
        let address_type: UInt8         
        let timestamp: Date             
        let state: UInt8                
        let category: UInt8             
        let eStatus: UInt8              
        let lat: Double                 
        let lon: Double                 
        let speed: UInt32               
        let altitude: UInt32            
        let vRate: Int32                
        let dir: UInt32                 
        let sil: UInt8                  
        let dass: UInt8                 
        let navil: UInt8                
        let accH: UInt8                 
        let accV: UInt8                 
        let accVeloc: UInt8             
        
        let extID: String               
    }

    let batchID: String
    let data: [adslAircraft]
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()  
        batchID = try container.decode(String.self)      // 1st String in array  
        data = try container.decode([adslAircraft].self) // following arrays of adslAircraft
    }
}
```

However, batchID and data is nil at decoding.

BTW, decoding using

```
let jsonArrayDecoder = JSONDecoder()
let safeSkyModel = try? 
jsonArrayDecoder.decode(udpSafeSkyPost.self, from: data!)
// or let safeSkyModel = try? jsonArrayDecoder.decode([udpSafeSkyPost].self, from: data!)
```

does fail with error as it expects key pairs in the data.

Comment: Remove the `try?` use a proper `do/catch` and add the complete error message to the question.

Comment: It's very complicated to decode this JSON with `Decodable` because the subarrays are heterogenous (`String` and `Int`) and you have to assign each single value to the properties. I guess it's less effort to decode with `JSONSerialization`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So at first, you decided to do, since it's an array and want each value for a specific property, you did:

```
var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()  
batchID = try container.decode(String.self)  //First item
data = try container.decode([adslAircraft].self) //Rest
```

You were on the right track, but if you follow your logic, you should do the same for `adslAircraft`:

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
    self.version = try container.decode(String.self)
    self.address = try container.decode(String.self)
    self.address_type = try container.decode(UInt8.self)
    ...
}
```

Then, on a `unkeyedContainer()`, each time you call `decode(_:)`, it will iterate, so when you get the `batchId`, the next one will be the next item, which is an array. But that's not "all the other items", you need to loop, with `while !container.isAtEnd {}`.

Working code:

```
let jsonStr = """
["mJv8P81",["0","4B43AC",4,1675445326,2,3,1,47.40967,8.9179,46,956,0,267,0,0,0,7,3,0,"HB-ZQI"],["0","DE007A",9,1675445313,2,5,1,50.42467,9.19857,0,518,0,180,0,0,0,5,3,0,"TEST"],["0","DD0B25",9,1675445322,2,3,1,51.9966,8.55458,39,454,-2,293,0,0,0,7,3,0,"D-HVBI"],["0","D005CE",9,1675445326,2,3,1,52.40545,9.77742,40,304,0,324,0,0,0,7,3,0,"D-HDSX"],["0","3B7B9E",4,1675445308,2,3,1,43.89118,4.92555,47,454,-2,330,0,0,0,7,3,0,"F-ZBPM"]]
"""

struct UDPSafeSkyPost: Decodable {
    let batchID: String
    let data: [ADSLAircraft]

    struct ADSLAircraft: Decodable {
        let version: String
        let address: String
        let address_type: UInt8
        let timestamp: Date
        let state: UInt8
        let category: UInt8
        let eStatus: UInt8
        let lat: Double
        let lon: Double
        let speed: UInt32
        let altitude: UInt32
        let vRate: Int32
        let dir: UInt32
        let sil: UInt8
        let dass: UInt8
        let navil: UInt8
        let accH: UInt8
        let accV: UInt8
        let accVeloc: UInt8
        let extID: String

        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
            self.version = try container.decode(String.self)
            self.address = try container.decode(String.self)
            self.address_type = try container.decode(UInt8.self)
            self.timestamp = try container.decode(Date.self)
            self.state = try container.decode(UInt8.self)
            self.category = try container.decode(UInt8.self)
            self.eStatus = try container.decode(UInt8.self)
            self.lat = try container.decode(Double.self)
            self.lon = try container.decode(Double.self)
            self.speed = try container.decode(UInt32.self)
            self.altitude = try container.decode(UInt32.self)
            self.vRate = try container.decode(Int32.self)
            self.dir = try container.decode(UInt32.self)
            self.sil = try container.decode(UInt8.self)
            self.dass = try container.decode(UInt8.self)
            self.navil = try container.decode(UInt8.self)
            self.accH = try container.decode(UInt8.self)
            self.accV = try container.decode(UInt8.self)
            self.accVeloc = try container.decode(UInt8.self)
            self.extID = try container.decode(String.self)
        }
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        batchID = try container.decode(String.self)      // 1st String in array

        var data: [ADSLAircraft] = []
        while !container.isAtEnd {
            let tempData = try container.decode(ADSLAircraft.self) // following arrays of adslAircraft
            data.append(tempData)
        }
        self.data = data
    }
}

do {
    let jsonArrayDecoder = JSONDecoder()
    jsonArrayDecoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
    let safeSkyModel = try jsonArrayDecoder.decode(UDPSafeSkyPost.self, from: Data(jsonStr.utf8))
    print(safeSkyModel)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Perfect shot! Thx a lot!! and explanation is understood ;-)

For purpose of consistency, just replace 'ADSLAircraft' by 'adslAircraft' (correct data type)

And, should the data structure match my sample, use:
    let safeSkyModel = try jsonArrayDecoder.decode(udpSafeSkyPost.self, from: data!)

Comment: By convention, struct/class names should start with an uppercase, that's why I renamed them.